# How to make multiple columns Unique using Javascript, Parse cloud code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

Im new to javascript and im unable to make multiple columns unique in the Database. So that user cannot save the data if it already exists in the Database. Im trying do this in Parse cloud main.js file.

I have custom user Profile class (**UserProfile**) with userName, emailId & phoneNumber and i would like this to remain unique.

Below is the Cloud code which im not able to expand on for all the three columns. But it works fine only for userName

```
var UserProfile = Parse.Object.extend("UserProfile");

                       if (!request.object.get("userImage")) {
                   response.error('User must be unique');
                   } else {
                   var query = new Parse.Query(UserProfile);
                   query.equalTo("userImage", request.object.get("userImage"));
                   query.first({
                               success: function(object) {
                               if (object) {
                               response.error("User already exists");
                               } else {
                               response.success();
                               }
                               },
                               error: function(error) {
                               response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this user.");
                               }
                               });
                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mongodb with parse:

I used Robomongo(GUI tool for mongodb) to add indexes in the database. There you can add the this index in userProfile class:

`index db.createIndex({userName:1, emailID:1,phoneNumber:1}, {unique:true})`

Then if someone tries to override this index, mongodb will throw an error. I learned a lot about mongodb indexes by watching several youtube videos about "mongodb indexing". Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, i will give it a try.